# Kubuntu doesn't start desktop environment half the time booting

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu installed, dual booting with Win10 and half the time I start my computer the desktop environment for Kubuntu just doesn't start, all I see is a blinking underscore. I can access tty and log in, which is helpful when I need to commit some work I hadn't committed. But I can't seem to get desktop to start half the time, the other half it works like a dream.

Comment: You could mention the version of Kubuntu. And consider asking at https://www.kubuntuforums.net as well. Providing your specs via `inxi -Fxz` may also be helpful. Install `inxi` from the repos.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and my issue was that `sddm-greeter` was not able to start properly as it couldn't find the theme for the login screen.

You can find the config file for `sddm` under `/etc/sddm.conf` (if it isn't there, check the man pages `man sddm` and it should tell you where the config file is under the heading Files.)

For me, changing the current theme to `breeze` and restarting `sddm` fixed my issue.

Comment: ill try this and get to you in a couple of days to see if the issue persists!